# unable to get personID in Xamarin.Microsoft.Cognitive.Face for MS-Cognitive

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, azure-cognitive-services

I am working on Face Recognition project using Microsoft Cognitive Services (Face API) in Xamarin application. To talk with Cognitive Services I used Xamarin.Microsoft.Cognitive.Face. Till now I am able to detect the Face by images and successfully identified the person.
Code for what I did:

```
 var faceServiceClient = new FaceServiceRestClient("https://australiaeast.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0", "KEY_GOES_HERE");
            var faceAttributes = new FaceServiceClientFaceAttributeType[] { FaceServiceClientFaceAttributeType.Gender, ........ };
            Com.Microsoft.Projectoxford.Face.Contract.Face[] result = faceServiceClient.Detect(@params[0], true, false, faceAttributes);
            var faceIds = result.Select(face => face.FaceId).ToArray();
            var results = faceServiceClient.Identity(personGroupId, faceIds, 5);
```

In above code I do get the Face detected (by `Detect()`) with `FaceID` and Candidate (by `Identity()`) stored in results variable. Now, I want to use `GetPerson` method to get the name of identified Face, for that I need `personID`. when I was debugging I expanded `results` but I did not got any `personID`. Now to get the Name of identified person do we have only `GetPerson()`? If YES, then can you please suggest me how to get `personID` by posting `FaceId` & `personGroupID`?

Thank You.

Comment: Has this PersonGroup been trained?  Here's the [code](https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Face-Android/blob/994f0b360aac19f1cbd94c759f494bb6ce8a0552/ClientLibrary/lib/src/main/java/com/microsoft/projectoxford/face/FaceServiceRestClient.java#L225).  Note that training is an async task.

Comment: Yes, PersonGroup has trained

Comment: Any help from anyone???

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide the content in the 'results'? If no person is identified, the Identify call should return an empty array. But if some person is identified, there should be faceId and confidence returned in the Candidates array. Also, you can use the [Get Person Group API](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395246) to check how many and which personIds are under your personGroupID